# Pulling variables in PHP across files into classes

Tags: php, class, global-variables

I have the following:

config.php

```
class myObject {
    public $_access_token;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_access_token = '';
    }
}
```

I need to pull the _access_token. Is this the best way to do it?
index.php:

```
require("config.php");
class gotime
{
    public function getAccessToken(){
        $obj = new myObject();
        return $obj->_access_token;
    }
```

Can I create the class outside the public function? It seems so inefficient to be putting a class creation in every function. I have another 12 variables I need to pull across files and I would like to set them in one place.

Comment: If you have no. of variables, which you want to use through out the execution of program make them `static`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use them like this.

```
class myObject 
{
    public static $_access_token;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        self::$_access_token = 'some value';//set the value you want
    }
}

echo myObject::$_access_token;
```

Comment: @Shail so it works if I put the variable info outside of the __Construct function.

Comment: You haven't set any value that is why it is displaying null;

Comment: @FrankThornton You can put the variable info in the variable declaration instead of __construct